# Print docstring from class, function, method, module

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

The documentation string (docstring) is like a comment; but used in different way. It is used to give brief info of any class, function, method, module, etc. It is not mandatory but obligatory for source code.

Docstring give the code more readability and understanding.
Print the documentation string (docstring) from module, function, class, or method definition.

```
class Test(object):
    ''' class documentation '''
    var = 5                             

    def __init__(self):
        ''' init(constructor) documentation '''
        self.var = 9                    

    def change(self):
        ''' change(self) '''
        self.var = 13
        print self.var

    def __del__(self):
        print "Destructor deleting object - ", self.var

cls = Test()

print Test.__doc__
print cls.__init__.__doc__
print cls.change.__doc__

print Test.var
print cls.var
cls.change()

def PrintDoc():
    """ inside PrintDoc """
    new = 12

print PrintDoc.__doc__
```

Comment: That's not a function so it doesn't have a docstring. Just create a main function and do `if __name__ == '__main__' : main()`. That's the preferred approach anyhow.

Comment: @Voo: Does any syntax mistake in your solution. Bcz I tried it and gettin an IndentationError.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can print the module's docstring:

```
"""This module does things"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print __doc__
```

Or just have a `main` function:

```
def main():
    """What I do when ran as a script"""
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print main.__doc__
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

So, in effect you want to print the docstring of the current module, right? A docstring needs to be the first string in the file. You can't put it after the `if` statement as in your code sample - that isn't a docstring anymore.

But if it's at the top of the file, you can simply

```
print __doc__
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. So you mean to say that I can not print the docstring inside any of the loop like if, for, while. Is it ? Please correct me if my understanding is wrong

Comment: @akD: You can print the docstring wherever you want. The docstring itself must be at the top of the file.