# How to set the output of `print(f)` for a function f

Tags: python

For various functions in Python, if I run `print(f)` it will spit something out. For instance,

```py
print(print)
```

which spits out

```
<built-in function print>
```

Now when I define

```py
def f(x):
    return x
print(f)
```

This spits out

```
<function f at 0x7f3800fe8dd0>
```

Is there a way to control what it spits out? I'd like to put my own custom string in but I'm not sure how to do that. I know how to do that for classes, but I had trouble finding a way to do that for functions.

Comment: You can, of course, make classes that act like functions (by defining `__call__`).

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35485125/print-docstring-from-class-function-method-module) help at all?

Comment: Basically, you are seeing the output of the `__str__` method (implicitly invoked by `print`) of whatever type your argument has.

Answer (score 4):

Create your own class which implements `__str__` and `__call__`:

```py
class Function:
    def __init__(self, func, disp):
        self.func = func
        self.disp = disp
    def __str__(self):
        return self.disp
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwds):
        return self.func(*args, **kwds)

def f(x):
    return x

# Pass the function as the first parameter, and the display string as the second
my_func = Function(f, 'my_func Function')
print(my_func)
print(my_func('abc'))
```

Output:

```
my_func Function
abc
```